# UITableViewCells quickly flash under certain circumstances

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I've spent a few hours on this and cannot figure out why my UITableViewCells all flash/blink (the only way I can explain it) when:

1. all my posts are loaded
2. I refresh and remove all objects from array and load the 1st page of refreshed results
3. I scroll down to the end of the first page and add the second page to my array.
4. all my post flash/change positions and then go back to normal (its really fast but looks bad)

This only happens when all the posts are loaded and then I refresh and it doesn't happen to the 3rd+ pages, only the 2nd.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)setup
{

    nearbyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    nearbyCellHeight = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    isLoadingMorePosts = YES;
    didLoadAllNearbyObjects = NO;
    isRefreshing = NO;

    totalNearbyObjects = 0;
    querySkip = 0;


    [self query];
}



- (void)refreshControlValueChanged:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh 
{
    NSLog(@"refreshing");

    if (!isRefreshing){
        didLoadAllNearbyObjects = NO;
        isRefreshing = YES;
        querySkip = 0;
        totalNearbyObjects = 0;
        refreshControl = refresh;
        [self query];

    }
}


- (void)query 
{

    NSLog(@"loading");

    int querylimit = 25;
    PFQuery *placeQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"places"];

    if (querySkip > 0) {
        [placeQuery setSkip: querylimit * querySkip];
    }

    [placeQuery setLimit:querylimit];
    [placeQuery whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:[LocationController sharedSingleton].locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:[LocationController sharedSingleton].locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude] withinMiles:
     200];

    [placeQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            [self handleQuery:objects];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            isLoadingMorePosts = NO;
        }
    }];
}


- (void)handleQuery:(NSArray *)objects
{
    if (isRefreshing){
        [nearbyArray removeAllObjects];
        [nearbyCellHeight removeAllObjects];
        isRefreshing = NO;
    }

    [nearbyArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];


    //determine if all objects are already loaded
    if (totalNearbyObjects != nearbyArray.count)
        totalNearbyObjects = nearbyArray.count;
    else
        didLoadAllNearbyObjects = YES;

    isLoadingMorePosts = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
    refreshControl.endRefreshing;
}


-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height)) {
        if (!isLoadingMorePosts) {
            if (didLoadAllNearbyObjects == NO){
                isLoadingMorePosts = YES;
                querySkip++;
                [self query];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean a white line across the screen and it disappers next second while refreshing?

Comment: Nope, I mean all the posts jump to a different indexpath.row and then jump back to normal. Really fast but extremely noticeable. And not while refreshing, while loading the 2nd page

Comment: Are you using -reloadData on tableView? TableView cells do flash when table view is reloaded. You can try reloading particular cells instead of whole table

Comment: I don't think that would be the problem since it only occurs when the circumstances I stated above are met